# Retrieving SVG position in Firefox vs Chrome with viewBox set

Tags: firefox, svg

I'm trying to get the left position of an svg element that has a viewBox set. The viewBox is basically a square, while the actual svg element is more rectangular. In most cases, this isn't a problem (and in Chrome, everything works fine), however, when trying to get the left position of the element within Firefox, as the viewBox is square, Firefox reports the left position of the viewBox rather than the svg element.

See http://jsfiddle.net/c6SW6/11/ for an example which should make things obvious.

Basically, in Chrome, the number reported for the left position is 8 This is the number that I want. In Firefox, it's reported as 108. How do I get Firefox to report the number 8 as well?

## Code

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><rect x=0 y=0 width=100 height=100></rect></svg>
</div>

<p>
</p>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
}

svg {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

#### JS

```
$('p').text($('svg').offset().left);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming we gave the rect an id="r" attribute...

If you just want the offset of the rect in the svg itself then it's

```
    $('p').text(document.getElementById("r").getCTM().e);
```

If you want the offset from the page origin instead...

- Call rect.getBoundingClientRect() and the left and top will contain the answer

  ```
  $('p').text(document.getElementById("r").getBoundingClientRect().left);
  ```
- or alternatively rect.getScreenCTM() the e and f members of the result will be the answer

  ```
  $('p').text(document.getElementById("r").getScreenCTM().e);
  ```

If you rotate the svg using a transform then you'll get different answers, getBoundingClientRect() will give you an unrotated bounding rect but getScreenCTM will give you a transformed offset, since you're not doing that you can use either currently.

The 8 is the difference, i.e. the position of the  element element on the page. That's not consistent with the description but if you want 8 then it's:

```
    $('p').text(document.getElementById("r").getScreenCTM().e -
                document.getElementById("r").getCTM().e);
```

Comment: Both of those actually give the same incorrect 108 answer unfortunately.

Comment: This only helped me confirm that firefox handles viewbox differently. What solved my issue in the end was setting `transform-origin` to `0 0` instead of `center center`